# Django validate_unique returns 500 when invalid

Tags: python, django, unique

When trying to validate unique of two fields, which one of them is a field of a foreign key in the model, I used 'validate_unique'.
According to the [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#validationerror) it should return 400. I get 500.
This is how I use it:

In the models.py (model is Item and foreign is Spec. Tested fields are 'identifier' and 'container_id):

```
def validate_unique(self, exclude=None):
    u_item = Item.objects.filter(identifier=self.identifier)
    if u_item.filter(spec__container=self.spec.container).exists():
        uu_item = Item.objects.get(identifier=self.identifier)
        print("already Exists")
        print("item identifier: ", uu_item.identifier)
        raise ValidationError('Identifier must be unique per Container')

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.validate_unique()
        super(Item, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

As mentioned, when testing two items with same identifier and spec.container_id I do get an error, but the status code is 500 instead of 400.

UPDATE:
inserted the 'save' function to try-catch:

```
 def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        self.validate_unique()
        super(Item, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    except ValidationError as e:
        print("Error:", e)
```

now, it run 'save' anyway - in create() function under 'query.py'.

Comment: 500 is internal server error. May be there is some problem with the code. Did you try debugging with some print statements

Comment: yes. As you can see in the sample code I put 'print', which prints the required data.

Comment: Just to make sure, is this the DRF version of the ValidationError, not the one from django.core.exceptions?

Comment: Actually I wasn't aware there are two version. What's the difference? I see that I import from django.core.exceptions (and basically using DRF)

Answer (score 0):

From the django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/_modules/django/db/models/base/#Model.validate_unique) the code raises a validation error when unique constraint fails.

```
if errors: 
    raise ValidationError(errors)
```

The same thing is with your code, you are raising a validation error instead catching the error. Catching an error will not throw the error in your code. If you use try catch and catch the exception then you can send the appropriate response that status 400, message: id already exists.

```
try:
     self.validate_unique()
except ValidationError as e:
     print("Error: ",e)
     # send the error with status 400
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Where should the 'super(Item, self).save(*args, **kwargs)' be in that case?

Comment: put it in the try block. so if validate_unique goes without any errorthen only super .... will be called

Comment: I did it and it still saves the model. I now see that there is another 'save' in 'create' function under 'query.py'. Shouldn't the 'save' function override it also?

Comment: save function in create is used to automatically save the created model objects. You might have noticed in docs that when you use create method for a model object its not necessary to call save function. save function won't override that thing. If validate_unique fails you must not call `super(Item, self).save(*args, **kwargs)`

Comment: I don't run the 'super.save()' if validation fails. please see update.

Comment: try to check that what self.validate_unique is returning.

Comment: It raises an exception as it  should. but right after the 'save' function prints the error, it jumps to the 'create' function and saves the objects to DB.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147547/discussion-between-arpit-solanki-and-user2880391).